# HTML Canvas gradient only show one color

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, linear-gradients

I'm having problems with **Canvas gradient** it only shows the last color that I set on `gradient.__addColorStop__(offset,color)` method.

For example here is a piece of my code to understand better:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(10, 90, 200, 90);
gradient.addColorStop(1 / 10, "black");
gradient.addColorStop(1 / 5, "yellow");
gradient.addColorStop(1 / 1, "red");
let circle1 = new Circle(300, 250, 50, gradient);
circle1.draw(ctx);
```

That code only draw a red circle and do the same with any shape filled with the gradient, if i comment this line `gradient.addColorStop(1/1,"red");`then canvas draw a yellow circle, only read the last color. I tried the same code on jsfiddle.net and works perfectly, i dont know why my script wont work.

PD: Circle is a js object that i defined and works perfectly

Sorry for my english, if the post doesn't understand please tell me, is my first post on StackOverflow.
Thanks!

Comment: You need to define the gradient for where the circle will be (X=275 to X=325.) It's already reached red (stop 3) by X=200, since the gradient is defined from x=10 to x=200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CanvasGradients are relative to the context's transformation matrix, not to the shape you'll fill it with.

So in your example, since you are drawing an horizontal gradient, you set this gradient only in an area that goes from x:10 to x:200. Pixels before x:10 will have the value at index 0, and the ones after x:200 the one at index 1.
Since you are drawing your circle at 300,150 with a radius of 50, the minimal x position your circle will attain is 250, which is after your gradient index:1 and hence solid red.

Here is a visual demo of what happens:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(10, 90, 200, 90);
gradient.addColorStop(1 / 10, "black");
gradient.addColorStop(1 / 5, "yellow");
gradient.addColorStop(1 / 1, "red");

// draw a full rectangle to see how the gradient is actually rendered
ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(300, 150, 50, 0, Math.PI*2);
ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

To circumvent this, you have two ways:

- generate your CanvasGradient at the correct coordinates:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
// x1 & x2 are set to match the circle's position
let gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(250, 90, 350, 90);
gradient.addColorStop(1 / 10, "black");
gradient.addColorStop(1 / 5, "yellow");
gradient.addColorStop(1 / 1, "red");

ctx.fillStyle = gradient;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(300, 150, 50, 0, Math.PI*2);
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

- modify the context's transformation matrix to move your CanvasGradient:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(10, 90, 200, 90);
gradient.addColorStop(1 / 10, "black");
gradient.addColorStop(1 / 5, "yellow");
gradient.addColorStop(1 / 1, "red");

ctx.fillStyle = gradient;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(300, 150, 50, 0, Math.PI*2);
// our arc has been defined at the correct position
// we can now translate the context matrix so that only the fillStyle be moved
ctx.translate(230, 0);
ctx.fill();

// reset the default tranform matrix
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```